# click with coordinates using pywinauto only when a chosen program appears

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have a function that constantly clicks the given coordinates using the `pywinauto` module.

```
def move_mouse():
  while True:
    pywinauto.mouse.click(button='left', coords=(1097, 136))
    time.sleep(3)
```

My problem is that this function clicks on whatever window that appears. I want to limit it in a way that it waits for the chosen program to appear(in my case, it is chrome browser) and only then execute the rest of the function.
I tried to use the code below, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

```
app = pywinauto.Application()
app.connect(title="title")
window = pywinauto.timings.WaitUntilPasses(20, 0.5, lambda: app.window_(title="title"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
apps = Application().connect(title="My window's title")
my_app = apps["My window's title"]
```

You may also use this to find the appropriate window if there is more than one window found.

```
apps.print_control_identifiers()
```

Once you found your window, you can invoke methods from docs:
https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.application.html?highlight=application#module-pywinauto.application